# HTTP authentication and sessions

Tags: android, zend-framework, http-authentication, zend-acl

I've been trying to figure out how to do a HTTP authentication and then use the session to display pages in a webview in my android app. Could someone please provide som guidance (I would very much appretiate some sample code if possible).

I use Zend ACL on the server side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html)? It should do exactly what you need. It does have http auth.